# Java Changeable Code

Tags: java, function

I am going to declare and run a Task in my code, but this Task needs a function which is based on the input of user. (Like if user says > I have to use this) but since possibilities are too much I can't just overload.

So I need something like this;
If user says:

```
x+3/y+5
```

I will turn to this

```
Function(int x,int y)
{
    return x+(3/y)+5;
}
```

I will have this at a String. However normally my app waiting is:

```
Task a = new Task(int x,int y,new Function(int x,int y)
{
    return x+(3/y)+5;
});
```

So I have to be able to put my function that is created at the runtime as a code into parameter of my task. I have a Function class. Any suggestions?

Comment: What you are looking for is an *evaluator* for arithmetic expressions. The first step in doing this is *parsing* the string into an abstract syntax tree and then evaluating it. This isn't incredibly hard but quite some work to do. You should look for a library that provides what you need.

Comment: It is just an example, user may not look for an arithmetic expression, it could be a search filter on a data structure etc.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the input? This looks to be impossibly broad.

Comment: Ok for example, SQL Select command. User is going to give me a Select command but since this could have a lot of different comparisons inside of it, I couldn't find a way of making function overloading. So I thought maybe there is a way that I can parse my string as a function code to parameter of task class.

Comment: You need to tokenize your user's input string and place the operations on a stack. You will need to define all the *expected* operations. Alternatively, Java 8 comes with a JavaScript engine built-in called *"Nashorn*", so you could [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to get your result, but this is unsafe and should be avoided. More on [Oracle's Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html).

Comment: Your code example above is a math equation, then in comments you talk about SQL commands... I'm at a loss.

Comment: I thought the above math equation as specialized aggregation command. If there was an aggregation command for that math equation (which could have been also simply i+y) my function would be that. (Tasks will simply run over a table and use this function).

Answer (score 2):

I simply Googled for Java token evaluator and this result came up:

- *[Mathematical Expression Parsers in Java and C++ <sup>[technical-recipes.com]</sup>](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java-and-cpp/)*

This blog-post is a great resource for understanding [Reverse Polish Notation (RPN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). The post contains some code, which I have refactored below. I have moved code around and made the flow of things easier to understand.

You simply need to parse the tokens and place them on a stack. Then you evaluate the expression by popping items off the stack until you hit an operator, you will then evaluate all the items that have been popped off.

I have added logic to support `x` and `y` variables in the evaluator.

---

## Full code example

#### ExpressionDriver.java

```
package math;

public class ExpressionDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "x + ( 3 / y ) + 5";
        double x = 8;
        double y = 3;
        Double result = evaluate(expression, x, y);

        // x 3 y / + 5 + 14.0
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static Double evaluate(String expression, double x, double y) {
        String[] tokens = expression.split("[ ]+");
        String[] output = ExpressionParser.infixToRPN(tokens);

        // Build output RPN string minus the commas
        for (String token : output) {
            System.out.print(token + " ");
        }

        // Feed the RPN string to RPNtoDouble to give result
        return ExpressionParser.RPNtoDouble(output, x, y);
    }
}
```

#### ExpressionParser.java

```
package math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ExpressionParser {
    // Test if token is an operator
    private static boolean isOperator(String token) {
        return Operator.lookup(token) != null;
    }

    // Test associativity of operator token
    private static boolean isAssociative(String token, int type) {
        Operator op = Operator.lookup(token);

        if (op == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token: " + token);
        }

        if (op.getAssociativity() == type) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Compare precedence of operators.
    private static final int cmpPrecedence(String token1, String token2) {
        Operator op1 = Operator.lookup(token1);
        Operator op2 = Operator.lookup(token2);

        if (op1 == null || op2 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid tokens: " + token1 + " " + token2);
        }

        return op1.getPrecedence() - op2.getPrecedence();
    }

    // Convert infix expression format into reverse Polish notation
    public static String[] infixToRPN(String[] inputTokens) {
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

        // For each token
        for (String token : inputTokens) {
            // If token is an operator
            if (isOperator(token)) {
                // While stack not empty AND stack top element is an operator
                while (!stack.empty() && isOperator(stack.peek())) {
                    if ((isAssociative(token, Operator.LEFT_ASSOC) && cmpPrecedence(token, stack.peek()) <= 0)
                            || (isAssociative(token, Operator.RIGHT_ASSOC) && cmpPrecedence(token, stack.peek()) < 0)) {
                        out.add(stack.pop());
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                // Push the new operator on the stack
                stack.push(token);
            }
            // If token is a left bracket '('
            else if (token.equals(Token.OPEN_PAREN)) {
                stack.push(token);
            }
            // If token is a right bracket ')'
            else if (token.equals(Token.CLOSED_PAREN)) {
                while (!stack.empty() && !stack.peek().equals(Token.OPEN_PAREN)) {
                    out.add(stack.pop());
                }
                stack.pop();
            }
            // If token is a number
            else {
                out.add(token);
            }
        }

        while (!stack.empty()) {
            out.add(stack.pop());
        }

        return out.toArray(new String[out.size()]);
    }

    public static double RPNtoDouble(String[] tokens, double x, double y) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

        // For each token
        for (String token : tokens) {
            // If the token is a value push it onto the stack
            if (!isOperator(token)) {
                stack.push(token);
            } else {
                // Token is an operator: pop top two entries
                Operator op = Operator.lookup(token);
                Double d2 = getDouble(stack.pop(), x, y);
                Double d1 = getDouble(stack.pop(), x, y);
                Double result = op.getExpression().evaluate(d1, d2);

                // Push result onto stack
                stack.push(String.valueOf(result));
            }
        }

        return Double.valueOf(stack.pop());
    }

    public static Double getDouble(String token, double x, double y) {
        if (token.equals("x")) {
            return x;
        } else if (token.equals("y")) {
            return y;
        } else {
            return Double.valueOf(token);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Operator.java

```
package math;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum Operator {
    ADDITION(Token.PLUS, 0, Operator.LEFT_ASSOC, new Expression() {
        @Override
        public double evaluate(double a, double b) {
            return a + b;
        }
        @Override
        public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }
        @Override
        public float evaluate(float a, float b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }),
    SUBTRACTION(Token.DASH, 0, Operator.LEFT_ASSOC, new Expression() {
        @Override
        public double evaluate(double a, double b) {
            return a - b;
        }
        @Override
        public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
            return a - b;
        }
        @Override
        public float evaluate(float a, float b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    }),
    MULTIPLICATION(Token.ASTERISK, 5, Operator.LEFT_ASSOC, new Expression() {
        @Override
        public double evaluate(double a, double b) {
            return a * b;
        }
        @Override
        public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
            return a * b;
        }
        @Override
        public float evaluate(float a, float b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    }),
    DIVISION(Token.SLASH, 5, Operator.LEFT_ASSOC, new Expression() {
        @Override
        public double evaluate(double a, double b) {
            return a / b;
        }
        @Override
        public int evaluate(int a, int b) {
            return a / b;
        }
        @Override
        public float evaluate(float a, float b) {
            return a / b;
        }
    });

    // Associativity constants for operators
    protected static final int LEFT_ASSOC = 0;
    protected static final int RIGHT_ASSOC = 1;

    private static final Map<String, Operator> LOOKUP_MAP;

    static {
        LOOKUP_MAP = new HashMap<String, Operator>();

        for (Operator operator : Operator.values()) {
            LOOKUP_MAP.put(operator.getSign(), operator);
        }
    }

    private String sign;
    private int precedence;
    private int associativity;
    private Expression expression;

    private Operator(String sign, int precedence, int associativity, Expression expression) {
        this.sign = sign;
        this.precedence = precedence;
        this.associativity = associativity;
        this.expression = expression;
    }

    public static Operator lookup(String operator) {
        return LOOKUP_MAP.get(operator);
    }

    public String getSign() {
        return sign;
    }

    public int getPrecedence() {
        return precedence;
    }

    public int getAssociativity() {
        return associativity;
    }

    public Expression getExpression() {
        return expression;
    }
}
```

#### Expression.java

```
package math;

public interface Expression {
    int evaluate(int a, int b);

    double evaluate(double a, double b);

    float evaluate(float a, float b);
}
```

#### Token.java

```
package math;

public class Token {
    public static final String PLUS = "+";
    public static final String DASH = "-";
    public static final String ASTERISK = "*";
    public static final String SLASH = "/";

    public static final String OPEN_PAREN = "(";
    public static final String CLOSED_PAREN = ")";
}
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it did helped me in the project's other parts. Seems like I could override the function of a class when I created it (which I did not know before).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look into some expression language evaluators.  Some common choices:

[MVEL](https://github.com/mvel/mvel)

[Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/)

[SPel (if you are using Spring)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

There are a lot of choices of similar expression language, and you may even consider scripting engines like Groovy mentioned above, or Python, Ruby, Javascript (through Jython, JRuby etc).  In brief, what you can do is, feed to the expression evaluation engine the expression string with related data you want the expression to "see".  Result will be evaluated accordingly.